# Concatenate and update a line in a file

Tags: powershell

I am trying to append a string in a file but no luck. I am  using below code. Can you please help what is wrong here.

```
$line = Get-content -Path "$($toolsDir)\PIA_Old.txt" | Select-String -Pattern "channelAccess" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Line
$b = "(A;;0x3;;;S-1-5-32-548)"
$c = $($line)+$($b)
$c
$content = Get-content -Path "$($toolsDir)\PIA_Old.txt"
$content | ForEach-Object {$_ -replace "$line","$c"} | Set-Content -Path "$($toolsDir)\PIA_Old.txt"
```

Below is the sample content of the file

```
name: PIA
enabled: true
type: Admin
owningPublisher: 
isolation: Application
channelAccess: O:BAG:SYD:(A;;0x2;;;S-1-15-2-1)(A;;0x2;;;S-1-15-3-1024-3153509613-960666767-3724611135-2725662640-12138253-543910227-1950414635-4190290187)(A;;0xf0007;;;SY)(A;;0x7;;;BA)(A;;0x7;;;SO)(A;;0x3;;;IU)(A;;0x3;;;SU)(A;;0x3;;;S-1-5-3)(A;;0x3;;;S-1-5-33)(A;;0x1;;;S-1-5-32-573)
logging:
  logFileName: %SystemRoot%\System32\Winevt\Logs\PIA.evtx
  retention: false
  autoBackup: false
  maxSize: 2097152
publishing:
  fileMax: 1
```

I am trying to append the line which contain string "channelAccess". And the output which I am expecting look like this.

```
name: PIA
enabled: true
type: Admin
owningPublisher: 
isolation: Application
channelAccess: O:BAG:SYD:(A;;0x2;;;S-1-15-2-1)(A;;0x2;;;S-1-15-3-1024-3153509613-960666767-3724611135-2725662640-12138253-543910227-1950414635-4190290187)(A;;0xf0007;;;SY)(A;;0x7;;;BA)(A;;0x7;;;SO)(A;;0x3;;;IU)(A;;0x3;;;SU)(A;;0x3;;;S-1-5-3)(A;;0x3;;;S-1-5-33)(A;;0x1;;;S-1-5-32-573)(A;;0x3;;;S-1-5-32-547)
logging:
  logFileName: %SystemRoot%\System32\Winevt\Logs\PIA.evtx
  retention: false
  autoBackup: false
  maxSize: 2097152
publishing:
  fileMax: 1
```

Comment: Looks like [`yaml`](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML), in which case I highly recomment you to use a yaml parser as https://github.com/cloudbase/powershell-yaml rather than peeking and poking arround string operators

Comment: Good advice in general @iRon; while it definitely looks like YAML in principle, the value that starts with `%` makes it invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your *immediate* problem is that the [`-replace` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#replacement-operator) is [regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions)-based, so the string value in `$line` needs *escaping* to ensure that regex metacharacters such as `(` are used *verbatim*, which you can do with [`[regex]::Escape($line)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Escape).

However, since you're using `-replace` anyway, you can use it *alone* to both match and append to the line of interest:

```bash
(Get-Content -Path "$toolsDir\PIA_Old.txt") -replace '^channelAccess:.+', '$&(A;;0x3;;;S-1-5-32-548)' |
  Set-Content "$toolsDir\PIA_Old.txt"
```

Note:

- `$&` in the substitution operand refers to what the regex operand matched, which is the *whole line* that starts with (`^`) `channelAccess:` (`.+` matches all remaining characters on the same line).

  - Note the use of a [*verbatim* (single-quoted) string (`'...'`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#single-quoted-strings), which is generally preferable in regex operations, to avoid confusion over whether a `$`-prefixed token is to be interpreted *by PowerShell*, in the context of *string expansion* (interpolation) up front vs. what the .NET regex engine should see if you use [expandable (double-quoted) string (`"..."`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#double-quoted-strings)
  - If you want to express the string to append via a *variable*, you could either do `` "`$&$b" `` (note how the first `$` is *escaped* as `` `$ ``) or `('$&' + $b)`
  - For an explanation of the regex and substitution operation and the ability to experiment with it, see [this regex101.com page](https://regex101.com/r/yYWIjY/1).
- Any lines that do *not* match the regex are passed through without modification.